# Json_Decode Object Remains NULL / Empty

Tags: json

I have a json_decoded response that looks like this:

```
string(664) "{ "ticker": "AAPL:US" }"
```

Now I am using json_decode with 'true' to access the data as an object:

```
print_r(json_decode($res));
```

When trying to dump the content it remains NULL

```
 var_dump($res->ticker);
```

How would I access the data without an array just the object?

EDIT: It remains 0 when using an array or an object. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major issues with your code:

1) When your second parameter is set to `true`, returned object will be converted into associative array. You have to set it to `false` (it's default value anyway).

2) `json_decode` does not change the value of `$res`, instead, it will return value encoded in `json` in appropriate type (mainly object or associative array).

Try this:

```
$res = '{ "ticker": "AAPL:US" }';

$obj = json_decode( $res, false );

var_dump( $obj );
```

Comment: Nope I tried that, for some reason it remains empty. When working with an array it somewhat works when accessing it like $res['body'][0] but it will spit out like a single letter instead of the item. Very strange

Comment: Thanks, I am using the exact code to test this and var_dump still shows NULL

Comment: Can you give us your whole code? You can use `pastebin` to share it.

Comment: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["ticker"]=> string(7) "AAPL:US" } 

=> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
=> NULL ..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/v4R7Bqbf .. been looking to long at this, it worked a couple days ago, same setup. Very strange

Comment: Ok got it now, thanks. Just went through that sample again. Just messed up the proper assignment